# MVC custom login view calls wrong ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've using the AspNet Framework 4.6 Membership framework with the default Account controller.
However I've customized it by adding a separate login view for a particular type of user.
The view file in Views/Account is called DirectoryLogin.cshtml

The header for the HttpPost ActionResult is ...

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> DirectoryLogin(ExternalLoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
```

The view displays fine when you go to the  http://[my_domain]/Account/DirectoryLogin URL, but when you hit the Submit (ie Log In) button, the ActionResult method that is called is always the default Login, ie...

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
```

There's obviously some unexpected "magic" going on under the hood. I only work in Asp.Net MVC infrequently, but my understanding has been that a view would always call the controller action with the corresponding name.

If you have any idea what I'm doing wrong, please let me know.

Comment: No, views don't always post to the same action that created them.  By default, they will post to the current URL which isn't necessarily the action method that created it. And they're often customized to post to different URLs. You'd have to actually look at the view to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the form helper inside your view. It may have something related to your problem. It may be like this code:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post)) {`

It means you are posting to Login action when the button is clicked.
Another thing to get to the solution is to debug it using breakpoints inside your code and see that whether it is even posting to the required action method.

Without complete code, it is not possible to get to the source of the problem. if possible, please include more code. Thanks

Comment: You're right, I had "Login" instead of "DirectoryLogin" in the BeginForm.

Comment: PS: Thanks for answering!